# How to get the component triggered in parent vue?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using Laravel 6 (mix) + Vue.js 2.

I am creating a multi-lang dictionary where users can add words and for each word they can add multiple definitions with their translations.

Inside `index.blade.php`

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-addItem">
    <form>
        <div class="card" v-for="(value, index) in nbDefinitions">
            <div class="card-header">@{{ value }}.</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <dl class="row">
                    <dt class="col-sm-3">English</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-9">
                        <autocomplete data-language="english" :search="searchDefinition" :get-result-value="getDefinitionResultValue" @submit="handleSearchDefinitionSubmit"></autocomplete>
                    </dd>
                    <dt class="col-sm-3">French</dt>
                    <dd class="col-sm-9">
                        <autocomplete data-language="french" :search="searchDefinition" :get-result-value="getDefinitionResultValue" @submit="handleSearchDefinitionSubmit"></autocomplete>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addItems-addDefinition" @click="addDefinition">+ Add definition</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Inside `myCustom.js`

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#modal-addItem',
    data:  {
        nbDefinitions: 0,
        nbSentencesPerDef: [],
        translatedDefinitions: []
    },
    methods: {
        addDefinition: function() {
            this.nbDefinitions++;
            this.nbSentencesPerDef.push(1);
            this.translatedDefinitions.push({
                english: null,
                french: null
            });
        },
        searchDefinition: function (input) {
            // How can I know which <autocomplete> is triggered?
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                if (input.length < 3) { return resolve([]); }
                fetch(`/api/v1/definitions?search=${encodeURI(input)}`)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(responseJson => {
                    resolve(responseJson.definitions);
                })
            })
        },
        getDefinitionResultValue: function(result) {
            // How can I know which <autocomplete> is triggered?
            let definition = result.definition;
            let item = result.item.name;
            return `${item} - ${definition}`;
        },
        handleSearchDefinitionSubmit: function(result) {
            // How can I know which <autocomplete> is triggered?
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
});
```

I am using `autocomplete` which is an external component loaded globally (in Laravel main app.js) https://autocomplete.trevoreyre.com/#/

My question is: How can I know inside the methods “addDefinition”, “searchDefinition” and “handleSearchDefinitionSubmit” what is the child component who was triggered? Because I have 3 autocomplete components inside my Vue object, and `this` refers to the root (in my case the html modal), so I have no idea which autocomplete child was triggered. Also this.$refs is empty.

Maybe it is an architectural issue, but I don’t have enough experience to know how to get it done.

Comment: are you hardcoding the languages like you show in your example? If so, you could always create `searchEnglishDefinition`, `searchFrenchDefinition` etc which call searchDefinition like `searchDefintion(input, 'english')`

Comment: or - look at [this issue](https://github.com/trevoreyre/autocomplete/issues/26) - it's not exactly what you are asking about, but it may shed some light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component itself doesn't support this directly (by passing itself as a parameter of functions for example). But luckily in case of functions passed as props we can use JS feature called "closure" - instead of just function name, call a function which returns another function. In case of events, we can use the feature of Vue allowing us to access special '$event' value when defining handlers.

Like this:

- before: `<autocomplete data-language="english" :search="searchDefinition" @submit="handleSearchDefinitionSubmit" />`
- after: `<autocomplete data-language="english" :search="getSearchDefinitionFunc('english')" @submit="handleSearchDefinitionSubmit($event, 'english')" />`

...and change your methods like this:

```
    getSearchDefinitionFunc(lang) {
      return input => this.searchDefinition(input, lang);
    },
    searchDefinition: function(input, lang) {
      console.debug(`searchDefinition called with "${input}" and "${lang}"`);

      if (input.length < 3) {
        return Promise.resolve([]);
      }

      // ...don't create new Promise, just return an existing one
      return fetch(`/api/v1/definitions?search=${encodeURI(input)}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => responseJson.definitions);
    },
    handleSearchDefinitionSubmit: function(result, lang) {
      console.log(`Submit: ${lang}`);
    }
```

I also refactored your code a bit as creating new promise is not necessary.

You can find working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-fey5j)

Could be refactored even more by defining your languages in component data (`['english', 'french']`) and generating each row using `v-for`